# How do I pass div inside a link_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to pass a div inside a `link_to` statement. This is not working for me:

```
 <%= link_to :controller => 'abouts', :action => 'index', :anchor => 'teacher-account' do %>
    <div class="accordion-inner">
         About Me
    </div>
   <%= end %>
```

Comment: `<%= end %>` should be `<% end %>`. It's almost impossible to help you further if you don't post **what** error you're getting.

Comment: I'm not getting any error. It is just not working.

Comment: You said "I can an error when I do it this way." Is that incorrect? If so, please update your question and remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper supports some options to pass in the `url` and the `html` for example: `link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})`.

So you might be able to try this:

```
link_to('About me', { controller: 'abouts', action: 'index' }, anchor: 'teacher-account', class: "accordion-inner")
```